# How to create a custom formula using data validation that can sort columns using column numbers in Google Sheets?

Tags: sorting, validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I hope someone can help with a problem I’m facing. I’m pretty new to Data Validation using Custom Formulas so I’d appreciate your guidance. I hope I have explained the situation clearly. Thanks.

I want to use data validation in cell B1 (Portfolio Tab) which creates a drop down list of the number of columns (1 to 44). I want to use the list as a way to sort a table (Column Headers - C3:AT4).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qunKbFGNzzGU9lNCPFow8igkR_gaPudmanTK-WM43mA/edit#gid=58173089

By selecting 1 from the drop down list I want my table to be sorted in Descending order by Portfolio%. Then if I want to sort by Name in Descending order I want to select 3 from the drop down list. Finally once I’m done sorting I want to revert back/reset to my original view. I want to do this without changing anything in columns A and B. Please assist. Thank You.

[Issue with using asc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbJHV.png)

[Issue with using asc (blank formula)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzUyu.png)

[Query and hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yq73.png)

[Query and hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je7DS.png)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 Apologies! Here is the sheet.  

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qunKbFGNzzGU9lNCPFow8igkR_gaPudmanTK-WM43mA/edit#gid=58173089

The desired output should look something like this: 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qunKbFGNzzGU9lNCPFow8igkR_gaPudmanTK-WM43mA/edit#gid=517791295

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: You can view it now

Answer (score 0):

## solution 1:

forget dropdown and use `filter view` inmerge row 3 & 4

[image]

delete row 1 & 4

[image]

select your range `C2:AT`

[image]

and creatte filter view

[image]

now you can sort one, multiple or all columns like:

[image]

---

## solution 2:

create a duplicate of your sheet:

[image]

delete your range `C3:AT`

[image]

use this in C3:

```
=QUERY({Portfolio!C3:AT}, "order by Col"&B1&" desc", 2)
```

[image]

---

## solution 3:

use sorting script... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script+sorting

Comment: Thank you so much. Solution 2 has been immensely helpful and has made my analysis very easy. Could you please help me out by extending the formula so I am able to choose if I want to sort by ascending or descending order.

Comment: @AmarPatel in A1 you can create dropdown from list: `asc,desc` then formula will be: `=QUERY({Portfolio!C3:AT}, "order by Col"&B1&" "&A1, 2)`

Comment: Ahh awesome! thank you so much it works nicely however there is one issue i'm facing when sorting by asc. Since I have formulas (IFERROR ETC) and some content in column AR-AU I basically have to scroll all the way down to find my data. I have attached two screenshots with the link showing the issue on the body at the top of the page called "issue with using asc". the second screenshot just shows what formula I have on the blank cells. Please help. thanks

Comment: @AmarPatel you can add `where Col1 is not null` before `order by`

Comment: It worked! Cant thank you enough. You're the best. I just have one final question then I'll stop bothering you lol. So when I'm using the query formula, the columns 4,5,9 which have hyperlinks are not showing up on the new sheet. I saw that query does not support hyperlinks. Do you know if there is a workaround for this so that i am able to use the hyperlinks in the new sheet? thanks

Comment: @AmarPatel query renders hyperlinks as plain text and there is no workaround for that

Comment: @AmarPatel did the answer solve your question?

Comment: Yes it did thank you very much! Can you think of any other way I could bring in the hyperlinks?